# Compact operators in $\bigoplus_{i \in I} H_i$

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, compact-operators

Let $\{H_i: i \in I\}$ be a collection of Hilbert spaces. We can form the Hilbert space direct sum
$$H:= \bigoplus_{i \in I} H_i$$

**Question**: Is there a "nice" dense subset of $B_0(H)$ (compact operators on the direct sum $H$)? For example, something like the operators
$$\left\{\bigoplus_{i \in I}  T_i \ \Bigg| \ T_i \in F(H_i), \text{all but  finitely many $T_i$ are zero}\right\}$$

where $F(H_i)$ are the finite-rank operators on $H_i$.

Comment: Your guess is correct and easy to prove because the projectors onto the sum of finitely many $H_i$ converge strongly to the identity.

Comment: Please check the edit.

Comment: @Ruy Thanks! Your edit was correct. If you want you can make your comment into an answer. Thanks!

Comment: Don't forget that $T_i$ should not be a finite rank map map $H_i\to H_i$ but rather $H_i\to H$. Alternatively you may write $\sum_{ij} T_{ij}$ with $T_{ij}: H_i\to H_j$ a finite rank map (and only finitely many $T_{ij}$ non-zero).

Comment: @s.harp I don't understand: $\bigoplus_i T_i((\xi_i)_i)= (T_i \xi_i)_i \in H$

Comment: As an example consider $\Bbb C^n = \Bbb C \oplus ... \oplus \Bbb C$. Your construction recovers only the _diagonal_ matrices. You still need to take care of the _off-diagonal_ terms.

Comment: @s.harp In that case $\bigoplus_i T_i(\xi_1, \dots, \xi_n) = (T_1\xi_1, \dots, T_n \xi_n)$. I'm not sure what you mean with diagonal matrices here?

Comment: Consider the linear map on $\Bbb C^2$ given by $\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$. You cannot approximate it because all your terms are diagonal.

Comment: @s.harp Thanks! I believe now I see the problem. You can make the above discussion in an answer if you like.

Comment: @s.harp,  of course you are correct!  And I was wrong to say the OP was correct in their claim.  The nice dense set is the union of the space of finite matrices over finite rank operators. I was about to write a full answer but perhaps you'd like to do it.

Comment: @Ruy go ahead, I just wanted to point something out :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me begin with a discussion of "operators vs. matrices", striving to make precise statements based on adjoints and
compositions   of operators, while avoiding the need to make  identifications between  sets, such as between a factor of a direct sum and its
canonical image.

---

Let $\{H_i\}_{ i \in I}$ be a collection of Hilbert spaces and put
$$
  H:= \bigoplus_{i \in I} H_i.
  $$
For each $i$, denote by $\iota _i:H_i\to H$ the  inclusion map and   observe that $\iota _i^*$ is precisely the projection from
$H$ onto $H_i$.
Incidentally, since $\iota _i$ is an isometry, then $\iota _i^*\iota _i$ is the identity on the domain of $\iota _i$ , while $\iota _i\iota _i^*$ is the orthogonal
projection onto $\iota_i (H_i)$, a.k.a. the canonical image of $H_i$ in $H$.  See $(\dagger)$ below regarding
a subtle conceptual distinction between $\iota _i\iota _i^*$ and $\iota _i^*$.

Given any bounded linear operator $T\in B(H)$, put
$$
  T_{i,j}=\iota _i^*T\iota _j, \quad \forall i,j\in  I,
  $$
so that each $T_{i,j}\in  B(H_j,H_i)$.  The "matrix" $(T_{i,j})_{i,j}$ may then be seen as the matrix of $T$ relative to the
above decomposition of $H$, and it can be used to recover $T$ in the following way:
given any vector $\xi \in  H$, write $\xi =(\xi _i)_{i\in I}$, so that each $\xi _i=\iota _i^*\xi $.
Noticing that $\xi =\sum_{j\in I} \iota _j\xi _j$, one then has for every $i$   that
$$
  \iota _i^*T\xi  = \sum_{j\in I} \iota _i^*T\iota _j\xi _j,
  $$
so, writing $T(\xi )=(\eta _i)_{i\in I}$, we see that the $i^{th}$ component $\eta _i$ of $T(\xi )$  may be computed in the familiar way as
$$
  \eta _i=\sum_{j\in I} T_{i, j}\xi _j.
  $$

Conversely, if $(T_{i,j})_{i,j}$ is any given matrix, with $T_{i,j}\in  B(H_j,H_i)$,  assume that $(T_{i,j})_{i,j}$  **has finitely many
nonzero entries**.   One can then define a bounded operator $T$ on $H$ by
$$
  T = \sum_{i, j} \iota _iT_{i,j}\iota^* _j,
  \tag 1
  $$
and it is easy to see that the matrix of $T$ coincides with the originally given matrix.
In case one moreover has that each $T_{i,j}$ lies in the set $K(H_j,H_i)$ of compact operators,  then $T$ is clearly
compact.  If instead each $T_{i,j}$ lies in the set $F(H_j,H_i)$ of finite rank operators, then $T$ has finite rank.

---

Directly addressing the question posed by the OP, the set formed by all operators built as in (1), from finitely
supported matrices $(T_{i,j})_{i,j}$, with each $T_{i,j}\in F(H_j,H_i)$, is a dense subspace of $K(H)$.  The proof may be
easily done by observing that the identity operator $1_H$ may be writen as
$$
  1_H = \sum_i \iota _i\iota _i^*,
  $$
with convergence in the strong operator topology,   and moreover noticing that left- or right-multiplication by compact operators turns
strong convergence into norm convergence.

---

$(\dagger)$ There is a subtle conceptual distinction between $\iota _i\iota _i^*$ and $\iota _i^*$ in the sense that both project
onto $H_i$, but the former  has $H$ for co-domain while the latter's  co-domain is $H_i$.  Co-domains are often
irrelevant in Math, but since the co-domain of an operator  becomes the domain of its adjoint, it is sometimes important to pay
attention to co-domains too!  In this note  all compositions $TS$ of operators are such that the domain of $T$ is *equal*
to the co-domain of $S$, even though for $TS$ to make sense, it is enough for the domain of $T$ to *contain* the range of $S$.